# Clustering customers based on their shopping baskets

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I would like to cluster customer based on their historical shopping baskets.

I have the following matrix describing each user and their corresponding amounts of purchased products. E.g. User 1 bought 0 of productA, 5 of productB and 6 of productC

UserID, productA, productB, productC 
1, 0, 5, 6 
2, 1,4,5 
3,9,1,0

What I would like to do:

- Cluster customers based on their bought products  (customer 1 and 2
  are very similar because both bought high amounts of productB and
  productC while customer 3 is more into productA)
- Visualize clusters

Problem:

- I have about 200.000 customers
- I have about 50.000 products (which can be grouped together into for
  example categories -> still will be more than 150 categories/a.k.a
  dimensions

Is there any recommended way to do such things in Python?

Comment: maybe check out `scikit` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html. Or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cluster/1.1.0b1 "python-cluster is a "simple" package that allows to create several groups (clusters) of objects from a list"

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look into pattern mining, in particular itemset mining

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_pattern_mining#Itemset_mining

an example project that may get you started:
https://github.com/jiteshjha/Frequent-item-set-mining

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I think this is not what I am looking for. As far as I understand, I need a function which calculates the similarity between each customer based on products they bought.

Comment: itemset pattern mining lets you determine what people buy together and what is the most common sequence of products bought, so you can predict what someone may buy next. if you're only looking at clustering, scikit-learn clustering functions are pretty straight forward, but the problem is feeding it a consistent dataset (i.e. a fixed nb of products per user) you might set a max and fill in thise under the max with blanks

Comment: Okay I understand your point and it is true. However this classification should not be used to do predictions but is part of my development towards a recommendation engine.